# entrar un form con javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Quiero poder recibir bien los parametros cada vez que selecciono mi boton radio.

Ya que decide si es un viaje redondo o sensillo , ahora lo que quiero es que se valide cuando yo lo selecciono
el problema es que al seleccionarlo no me esta mandando mis datos o bien es porque no los he escrito por que el radio button, cuando va al principio de mi form, en la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```JavaScript
on
NaN
24/09/2021
28/09/2021
Diste un click en select 1
>
```

Este es mi codigo que recibe y valida que solo haya 4 reservaciones:

```JavaScript
$('#switch').on('click', function() {
    var adultos = $('#adultos').val();
    var menores = $('#menor').val();
    var senectud = $('#inapam').val();
    var estudiantes = $('#estudiantes').val();
    var profesores = $('#profesores').val();
    var x = $('input:checkbox[name=switch]:checked').val();
    console.log(x);
    var bolmax = parseInt(adultos) + parseInt(menores) +  parseInt(senectud) + parseInt(estudiantes) + parseInt(profesores);
    console.log(bolmax);
    
    if ($('input[name="switch"]').is(':checked')) {
        if (bolmax > 4) {
            alert ( 'En viaje Redondo, Solo puedes seleccionar 4 o menos pasajeros para reservación');
            ok = false;
        }
    } 
});
```

Esta es la parte del form que mas me interesa:

```HTML
<form id="formulario" style="color: white;" method="post" action="https://localhost:44310/Paso1">
    <div class="form-row">
    <div style="text-align: end; right: 14px;" class="col-lg-12 mt-lg-5 mt-3 mr-3">
    <label style="width: 100%; font-size: x-small;" for="validationDefault05">REDONDO</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" name="switch">
```

Pero me manda a otro script que tengo que si me deja pasar y reservar el viaje a pesar que solo se acepten 4.

Answer (score 2):

Listo ya me quedo, solo tuve que reemplazar el nombre de mi cheaked para que los recibiera

```JavaScrip
var xr = $('input[name="switch"]').is(":checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
var bolmax = parseInt(adultos) + parseInt(menores) + parseInt(senectud) + parseInt(estudiantes) + parseInt(profesores);
console.log(xr);
if (xr == 'checked' && bolmax > 4) {
    msg = 'En viaje Redondo, Solo puedes seleccionar 4 o menos pasajeros para reservación';
    ok = false;
}else if (xr == 'unchecked' && bolmax > 6) {
    msg = 'En viaje Sencillo, solo puedes seleccionar 6 o menos pasajeros para reservación';
    ok = false;
}
```